# Removing front element and adding new element to min-heap (std::priority_queue)

Tags: c++, algorithm

Use case: I want to implement a very efficient send queue for a Linux program sending many rate-limited streams of large numbers of UDP packets per second in a network test program. Currently, I use a

```
priority_queue< pair<timespec, int>,
                std::vector<pair<timespec, int>>,
                std::greater<pair<timespec, int>> >
```

The program functions correctly and is fast. But I would like to be able to pop front of queue and add a new element in one operation, i.e. only one re-heapify per pop/emplace pair. Otherwise, the pop will re-heapify, and then the emplace will directly re-heapify again.

Can this be done with std::make_heap, std::push_heap and std::pop_heap? Or do I have to roll my own? My current program does pop followed by emplace on the std::priority_queue, which costs '2*O(log(N))'.

FWIW, the current program is here: https://github.com/alapaa/timestamping/tree/send_queue

The actual sender with queue is this src file:
https://github.com/alapaa/timestamping/blob/send_queue/manysock/sender.cpp

Comment: The solution pointed out as a  pre-existing duplicate (jxh:s answer) works well. I implemented it as a small wrapper class on top of std::make_heap, see https://github.com/alapaa/timestamping/blob/send_queue/manysock/send_queue.h

Answer (score 0):

Use deque as a container and make_heap to heapify. -->
Use vector as a container and make_heap using reverse iterator, and push at the back.
It will be a little faster.

```
vector<int> v{4,3,7,1,5};
make_heap(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), greater<int>());
for(auto& a : v) cout << a << ' ';
cout << endl;
q.pop_back();
q.push_back(9);
make_heap(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), greater<int>());
for(auto& a : q) cout << a << ' ';
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Does the standard guarantee that make_heap will be cheap (logarithmic) in this special case? I also would like to avoid using a deque, I prefer vector for speed. (size of q will not increase over time). I would like to just put the new element at the front of the vector, and then sift it down until I have re-established the min-heap property. Maybe best to roll my own.

Comment: If I am remembering correctly, make_heap is the same algorithm that is used in priority queue. So, if you intend to use priority queue, there is no reason to avoid using make_heap.

Comment: But for a std::priority_queue, you often just call make_heap once at the beginning (expensive), then just pop and push elements often (push and pop are logarithmic).

Comment: I wanted to say that the cost of using pri queue is more than using make_heap.

Comment: Why? std pri q is just an adapter/wrapper over make_heap, push_heap and pop_heap. And the algorithmic complexity is as it should be in a heap.

Comment: If the data size is very large, using deque and make_heap will be better. If you want to use vector, the data size should be small, then no need to worry about 2calls of heapifying.

Comment: That is not correct - the normal implementation of a prio q is based on a vector. And I pointed out the optimal solution to simultaneous remove and insert in my answer.

Comment: You may be right if you use vector and make heap using reverse iterator, And push at the back. This case will not need to implement your own either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I did not find this solution in my earlier searches on SO (look at jxh:s answer): [How to change max element in a heap in C++ standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662820/how-to-change-max-element-in-a-heap-in-c-standard-library)

Comment: if another question provides the answer to your question, then the correct approach is to mark your question as a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) of the other one. Not to post an answer with a link. I've put in my vote to do so.