# Single 'Heapify' call when removing max and adding a new element c++ std::make_heap

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap

Is it possible to pop the max, push a new element, and then call push_heap, maintaining the heap and only calling the bubble down algorithm once?

```
    // What I think is correct:
    heap.push_back(new_element);
    std::push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
    std::pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
    heap.pop_back();

    // What I hope is correct:
    heap.pop_back();        
    heap.push_back(new_element);
    std::push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
```

Is it 'safe' to remove the max and push a new element to a heap? I have tested it and it seems to be the case. Is there a reason I should not do this?

Very related question:
[How to change max element in a heap in C++ standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662820/how-to-change-max-element-in-a-heap-in-c-standard-library)

Comment: Won't the largest element be in the front, making 'pop_back()' incorrect?

Comment: Yes - thanks. My 'test' had an extra pop_heap statement I didn't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a max heap created via [`make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), the maximum element will be on the front, and the appropriate way to remove it is with [`std::pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap), period.

A `pop_front` (not `pop_back` like you posit) would indeed remove the maximum element from the heap, but you are no longer guaranteed to have a heap. That is, popping the first element effectively moves the heaps *left* child into the root. If the *right* child was bigger, then the heap property is lost (and even if it worked for the first set of children, it may invalidate any subtree on account of the shift in the array).

Additionally, if you're using a contiguous container like a `std::vector`, then a `pop_front` (calling [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) on [`vector::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)) has the misfortune to cost you O(N) time, which is much worse than the O(log N) complexity of `pop_heap`.

The one scenario that you may (prematurely) optimize for is if you simply want to *swap* the maximum element with another element that is at least as big as the existing maximum element, or failing that, >= to the maximum element's largest child. In that case you may achieve O(1) complexity, but this is unlikely in the general case.

It's better to just have two O(log N) operations. The function grows so slowly that there will hardly be a difference between 1000 and 1 million element heaps.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is nearly an exact duplicate of the linked question in your post body.

```
// Precondition is that v is already a heap.
int get_max_element_add_new (std::vector<int> &v, int value) {
    v.push_back(value);
    std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
    value = v.back();
    v.pop_back();
    return value;
}
```

Since `pop_heap` will swap the first and last values, the `back` will contain the max that you want to remove.